# Linq to Objects ordering by arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, sql-order-by, func

I have a list of `Func` defining an ordering:

```
var ordering = new List<Func<Person, IComparable>> 
                 { x => x.Surname, x => x.FirstName };
```

I can order the results with something like...

```
people = people.OrderBy(ordering[0]).ThenBy(ordering[1]);
```

I'm trying to figure how to do the above when the list can contain any number of sequential orderings. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
people = people.OrderBy(ordering[0]).ThenBy(ordering[1]).ThenBy(ordering[2]);
```

is the same as

```
var orderedPeople = people.OrderBy(ordering[0]);
orderedPeople = orderedPeople.ThenBy(ordering[1]);
orderedPeople = orderedPeople.ThenBy(ordering[2]);
people = orderedPeople;
```

so you simply write a loop like this:

```
if (ordering.Count != 0)
{
    var orderedPeople = people.OrderBy(ordering[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < ordering.Count; i++)
    {
        orderedPeople = orderedPeople.ThenBy(ordering[i]);
    }
    people = orderedPeople;
}
```

Comment: you actually don't need to check for a count, if you just switch what's being done in the loop

Comment: I didn't realise the "is the same as" bit was true for some reason. I thought they had to follow directly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hmmmm... actually they aren't the same. `ThenBy` operates on an `OrderedEnumerable<T>`, which is how I remembered it. I think I can work around that though.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, you can use a loop to do this.

If you prefer, you can also use the `Aggregate` operator:

```
// Requires a non-empty ordering sequence.
var result2 = ordering.Skip(1)
                      .Aggregate(people.OrderBy(ordering.First()), Enumerable.ThenBy);
```

(or)

```
// Shorter and more "symmetric" but potentially more inefficient.
// x => true should work because OrderBy is a stable sort.
var result = ordering.Aggregate(people.OrderBy(x => true), Enumerable.ThenBy);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do something similar to this

```
people = people.OrderBy(ordering[0])
foreach(var order in ordering.Skip(1))
{
  people = people.ThenBy(order);
}
```

Alternately

```
 for(i = 0; i < ordering.Count; i++)
 {
    people = i == 0 ? people.OrderBy(ordering[i]) : people.ThenBy(ordering[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that LINQ execution is deferred. You can build up the expression sequentially before accessing the results, doing something like:

```
var ordered = unordered.OrderBy(ordering.First());
foreach (var orderingItem in ordering.Skip(1))
{
    ordered = ordered.ThenBy(orderingItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this with dynamically building up you're expression. More info here: [Dynamic LINQ and Dynamic Lambda expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114029/dynamic-linq-and-dynamic-lambda-expressions)