# create dynamic query in EF in multi layer architecture and repository pattern

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, lambda

i want to create dynamic linq query or dynamic linq or lambda expression.
i am using [this article](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern-upgraded-to-ef-4-1/)
for example i want to tell to repository get products that their names start with 'computer' and (and sometimes or) their prices greater than 10 $.
i want to use lambda expressions or expression trees, i am beginner in this topics. 
in top article and in BLL Layer doesent exist any linq query. he use lambda expressions to pass values to repository. 
please tell me solution.

Comment: Did you look at the use of the specification pattern in his article?

Comment: please, write here an abstract post for specification pattern and tell me how specification pattern help me to create dynamic queries using lambda expressions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your application could fill in data like so:

```
var productName = "computer";
var minPrice = 10;

var products = _productRepository.Find(p => p.Name == productName && p.Price > minPrice);
```

Comment: thanks. but i want to create passed parameters dynamically based on user input in UI Layer

Comment: @PezhmanParsaee, this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114029/dynamic-linq-and-dynamic-lambda-expressions