# How to join two datatable for dynamic column in LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a two datatable dt1 and dt2 (which are generated in runtime) and i have to apply inner join query on this table.(EmpId is same in both table)

but the no of coloumns and their names are dynamic which are depends upon databse.

both table contains same coloumn name like table 1 have coloumn this table contains leave taken by employee "p" .he have not taken any sickleave so value is null.

```
EmpId Empname SickLeave Casual Leave  
1       P                   1
```

and table two have values like

```
 EmpId Empname  SickLeave Casual Leave  
    1       P       5           5
```

this table contain total leave given by a copmany to a employee (Max leave)

i have to join this query and show result like this

```
 EmpId Empname  SickLeave Casual Leave  
  1       P       0/5          1/5
```

so i want to know how can i join this two datable and show result like this using Ef and LINQ. (no of leave given two i.e sick leave ,casual leave but it may be three or 2 or 4 depend upon databese and its name also can be chage accoding to databse)

if any one have an idea please guide me

Answer (score 0):

If you really need dynamic Linq to entities then

**OPTION A) string to lambda**

Dynamic Expressions and Queries in LINQ
System.Linq.Dynamic    can be found at following links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx
http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/dynamiclinqcsharp.zip
[How to convert a String to its equivalent LINQ Expression Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-equivalent-expression-tree)

**OPTION B) Build expression trees**

A more thorough approach is to build expression trees. Build expressions trees with code found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx 
[Dynamic LINQ and Dynamic Lambda expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114029/dynamic-linq-and-dynamic-lambda-expressions)