# How to pass an Expression into Entity Framework LINQ query OrderBy clause

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6, expression

I have the following LINQ query:

```
using (var context = new EUContext())
        {
            var tmp = context.Terms.Include(x => x.StudentCourses)
                .Where(x => x.StudentID == studentId && x.DepartmentID == departmentId)
                .OrderBy(x => x.AcademicYear)
                .ThenBy(x=> x.TermRegistered == "Fall" ? 1 :
                            x.TermRegistered == "Spring" ? 2 : 3));

            return tmp.ToList();
        }
```

I am trying to move the OrdyBy in the ThenBy clause to clean up the code. I am trying to use an expression as following:

```
private static Expression<Func<string, int>> TermsOrder(string x)
        {
            return (x == "Fall" ? 1 :
                    x == "Spring" ? 2 : 3);
        }
```

and my code should look like this:

```
using (var context = new EUContext())
            {
                var tmp = context.Terms.Include(x => x.StudentCourses)
                    .Where(x => x.StudentID == studentId && x.DepartmentID == departmentId)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.AcademicYear)
                    .ThenBy(x=> TermsOrder(x.TermRegistered));

                return tmp.ToList();
            }
```

Unfortunately the expression doesn't work there is a long squiggly line in the body of the expression with the following error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>

What am I doing wrong? This is my first try on using expressions and I know that I am missing something obvious due to not fully understanding how expressions work.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest not to keep such data as string in database. If I were you I would change into into enum instead of string. You may have much more troubles later

Comment: The database is a production database and I am writing code to provide additional functionality. So altering the database is not an option for now.

Comment: Look at the type of the `return` statement - what are you returning? Look at the type of the `TermsOrder` function - what do you want to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't as simple as it seems. You need to combine `Expression`s or build `Expression`s to generate what you want, and unfortunately C# doesn't include a lot of help in that area.

The easiest approach is to use an extension method for `LambdaExpression` composition. It depends on some `Expression` extension methods for replacing one `Expression` with another in an `Expression`:

```
public static class ExpressionExt {
    // Compose: f.Compose(g) => x => f(g(x))
    /// <summary>
    /// Composes two LambdaExpression into a new LambdaExpression: f.Compose(g) => x => f(g(x))
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fFn">The outer LambdaExpression.</param>
    /// <param name="gFn">The inner LambdaExpression.</param>
    /// <returns>LambdaExpression representing outer composed with inner</returns>
    public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> Compose<T, TIntermediate, TResult>(this Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> fFn, Expression<Func<T, TIntermediate>> gFn) =>
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(fFn.Body.Replace(fFn.Parameters[0], gFn.Body), gFn.Parameters[0]);    

    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces a sub-Expression with another Expression inside an Expression
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orig">The original Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="from">The from Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="to">The to Expression.</param>
    /// <returns>Expression with all occurrences of from replaced with to</returns>
    public static Expression Replace(this Expression orig, Expression from, Expression to) => new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(orig);
}

/// <summary>
/// Standard ExpressionVisitor to replace an Expression with another in an Expression.
/// </summary>
public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    readonly Expression from;
    readonly Expression to;

    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
}
```

Now you can create your method that takes a lambda representing the field you want to test. It uses a local `LambdaExpression` as a template for the final result:

```
public static class Util {
    static Expression<Func<string, int>> TermOrderTemplateFn = p => (p == "Fall" ? 1 : p == "Spring" ? 2 : 3);
    public static Expression<Func<TRec, int>> TermsOrder<TRec>(Expression<Func<TRec, string>> selectorFn) =>
        TermOrderTemplateFn.Compose(selectorFn);
}
```

Now you can call the method in your expression, passing in a lambda representing the desired field (or field expression) to test:

```
var tmp = context.Terms.Include(x => x.StudentCourses).AsQueryable()
                .Where(x => x.StudentID == studentId && x.DepartmentID == departmentId)
                .OrderBy(x => x.AcademicYear)
                .ThenBy(Util.TermsOrder<Term>(p => p.TermRegistered));
```

**Note:** I am calling the type of `context.Terms.First()` `Term` but you would need to use the actual correct type name in the call to `TermsOrder`. You could also do `TermsOrder((Term p) => ...)` instead.

I would probably prefer to create a special version of `ThenBy` so you can use type inference to determine the record type:

```
public static class EFExt {
    static Expression<Func<string, int>> TermThenOrderTemplateFn = p => (p == "Fall" ? 1 : p == "Spring" ? 2 : 3);
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenByTerm<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> src, Expression<Func<T, string>> selectorFn) =>
        src.ThenBy(TermThenOrderTemplateFn.Compose(selectorFn));
}
```

Then you can use it directly:

```
var tmp = context.Terms.Include(x => x.StudentCourses).AsQueryable()
                .Where(x => x.StudentID == studentId && x.DepartmentID == departmentId)
                .OrderBy(x => x.AcademicYear)
                .ThenByTerm(p => p.TermRegistered);
```

Comment: BTW, I am still working on how to create a useful `Expressions` helper library that would make this stuff easier.

Comment: Is there any advantage to write `(Expression<Func<T, int>>)Expression.Lambda` instead of `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>`?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Absolutely no. I have no idea why people continue using cast when this overload exists. Probably because they don't know about it :)

Comment: What you call `Swap` is really `Replace` and usually is enough just to handle lambda parameter replacing (hence called `ParameterReplacer`). Also what you do here is referred as composing expressions by [several posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1159478+Compose) by Servy, for instance [Convert Linq expression “obj => obj.Prop” into “parent => parent.obj.Prop”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602729/convert-linq-expression-obj-obj-prop-into-parent-parent-obj-prop/37602870#37602870). Also there are already many libraries for doing that - LinqKit, NeinLinq, even AutoMapper.

Comment: But.. my previous comments doesn't mean this answer is not correct. Indeed it is and does solve the OP issue.

Comment: @IvanStoev I know about it, but it doesn't come to mind - I think because I expect generic parameters to be inferred, and am often annoyed when they are not. I don't expect to treat them like regular parameters.

Comment: @IvanStoev I feel like those libraries are too heavy weight for this and similar issues - look at what LINQKit would require in the query, for example. I like the name `Replace` though.

Comment: @IvanStoev Updated my answer to use functional programming compose terminology and suggest an `IOrderedQueryable` extension.