# Building Dynamic Where Clause with Generic filtering for field types

Tags: c#, linq

This questions stems from another closed one I posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972955/iqueryable-extension-method-with-dynamic-expression-passed-for-different-propert)

I have the following call

```
        var query = _context.Listings.AsQueryable();
        query = query.WhereEqualIfSpecified(x => x.HasBalcony, true);
        query = query.ApplyRangeFilter(x => x.BedroomsAvailable, 1, 9);
        query = query.ApplyRangeFilter(x => x.Baths, 1.0, 2.5);
        query = query.ApplyRangeFilter(x => x.Price, 1000.00, 2000.00);
        var listings = query.ToList();
```

I would like to make `WhereEqualIfSpecified` generic so its not only for bools but once I change the method to following

```
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereEqualIfSpecified<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, T>> fieldExpression, T filterValue)
    {
        return filterValue is null
            ? query
            : query.Where(fieldExpression.Compose(value => value.Equals(filterValue)));
    }
```

The call  `query = query.WhereEqualIfSpecified(x => x.HasBalcony, true);` results in compiler error

> The type arguments for method
>   'ExtensionMethods.WhereEqualIfSpecified(IQueryable,
>   Expression>, T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments explicitly

```
public partial class Listing
{

    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public int? BedroomsAvailable { get; set; }
    public double? Baths { get; set; }

    public bool? HasBalcony { get; set; }
    public bool? HasElevator { get; set; }

}
public static class ExtensionMethods
{

    public static IQueryable<T> WhereEqualIfSpecified<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool?>> fieldExpression, bool? filterValue)
    {
        return filterValue is null
            ? query
            : query.Where(fieldExpression.Compose(value => value.Equals(filterValue)));
    }



    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyRangeFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, int?>> filter, int? minValue, int? maxValue)
    {
        if (minValue is null && maxValue is null) return query;

        if (maxValue != null && minValue != null)
        {
            return minValue == maxValue?
                 query.Where(filter.Compose(value => value.Equals(minValue))):
             query.Where(filter.Compose(value => value >= minValue && value <= maxValue));

        }

        return query.Where(maxValue != null ? filter.Compose(value => value <= maxValue) : filter.Compose(value => value >= minValue));
    }


    //copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602729/convert-linq-expression-obj-obj-prop-into-parent-parent-obj-prop/37602870#37602870
    public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> Compose<T, TIntermediate, TResult>(
        this Expression<Func<T, TIntermediate>> first,
        Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(
            second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], first.Body),
            first.Parameters[0]);
    }

    public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly Expression from, to;
        public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
        {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression ex)
        {
            return ex == @from ? to : base.Visit(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Expression Replace(this Expression ex,
        Expression from,
        Expression to)
    {
        return new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(ex);
    }

}
```

In short, I would like both `WhereEqualIfSpecified` and `ApplyRangeFilter` to be generic so it can take any type in instead of using overload functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more generic type. In the field expression you say that the func takes a `T` and returns a `T`: `Expression<Func<T, T>> fieldExpression`. But it should take a `T` and return *some other type*.

```
public static IQueryable<TItem> WhereEqualIfSpecified<TItem, TFilterValue>(this IQueryable<TItem> query, Expression<Func<TItem, TFilterValue>> fieldExpression, TFilterValue filterValue)
{
    return filterValue is null
        ? query
        : query.Where(fieldExpression.Compose(value => value.Equals(filterValue)));
}
```

You will also need more `ApplyRangeFilter`, not only one handling `int`, but also `double` and `decimal`. Alternatively you could implement one taking `<TItem, TValue>` (not only `T`) and requiring that the `TValue` is a `struct` and `IComparable`. Then you could use the `CompareTo` of the value (instead of comparisons like `==` and `>=`). It would be slightly more complex, but you can reuse it for all value types in one stroke.

Here's an attempt:

```
public static IQueryable<TItem> ApplyRangeFilter<TItem, TValue>(this IQueryable<TItem> query, Expression<Func<TItem, TValue?>> filter, TValue? minValue, TValue? maxValue)
    where TValue: struct, IComparable
{
    if (minValue is null && maxValue is null) return query;

    if (maxValue != null && minValue != null)
    {
        return minValue.Value.CompareTo(maxValue.Value) == 0
            ? query.Where(filter.Compose(value => value != null && value.Value.Equals(minValue.Value)))
            : query.Where(filter.Compose(value => value != null && value.Value.CompareTo(minValue.Value) >= 0 && value.Value.CompareTo(maxValue.Value) <= 0));
    }

    return query.Where(maxValue != null
        ? filter.Compose(value => value != null && value.Value.CompareTo(maxValue.Value) <= 0) 
        : filter.Compose(value => value != null && value.Value.CompareTo(minValue.Value) >= 0));
}
```

Note that you will need to alter your call slightly so your min/max value types matches the property types: `query = query.ApplyRangeFilter(x => x.Price, 1000M, 2000M);`

**However**, it seems that the list of data comes from a EF data fetching. Be aware that these types of complex filtering requires the data to be filtered on the client side, i.e. fetching *all* data and then executing the queries in the application. If there is a lot of data this will be very slow and expensive.

Comment: I have fixed the WhereEqualIfSpecified as your answer, overloading the ApplyRangeFilter is whatI was trying to get away with but it seems that I may do that instead of complex generic version

Comment: Edited my answer with a more complex `ApplyRangeFilter`. Please mark as a correct solution if it works. :-)

Comment: above results in an in memory filter vs sql, which is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: Yes, you must keep your queries much more simple to get it to execute on the database server. So it that's your question you should either close this one (which didn't mention that at all) or (preferably) open a new one. But simply put; you cannot do any Expression-magic and expect it to be turned into a SQL query.

Comment: I will mark this one answered for the first part and figure out what to do with the second one without overloads